# Xcode Instruments: Color Blended Layers (pink vs red)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, instruments, asyncdisplaykit

I've just made some view background not transparent. But the blended layer remained while testing in **Instruments**. Only the color of blended layer changed from red to pink. I haven't found what does pink color mean. Any thoughts?

From documentation:

> Color Blended Layers. Shows blended view layers. Multiple view layers
>   that are drawn on top of each other with blending enabled are
>   highlighted in **red**. Reducing the amount of **red** in your app when this
>   option is selected can dramatically improve your app’s performance.
>   Blended view layers often cause slow table scrolling.

Here is the way my view looks after and before setting background to non transparent (look at labels with text):

[image]

Btw, these labels are not ordinary **UIKit** objects. They are `ASTextNode` objects from **Texture** framework.

**Edit**

It's not **Misaligned Images**, they have different colors:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other Debug Options selected, for example Color Misaligned Images?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist just color blended layers. Are there any other options which produce pink overlay?

Comment: If I remember correctly the Color Misaligned Images option will produce pink/magenta overlays for views/images that aren't pixel aligned and yellow overlays for views/images that are stretched/squashed.

Comment: @iWheelBuy I have the same issue, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Alessandro haven't solved...